# Typescript Extend Generic Interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-generics

I want to create an interface whereby I can extend any typescript type to add a property to extend a generic type. For example, create a `Confidence<any>` type that looks like this:

```
export interface Confidence<T> extends T{
   confidenceLevel:number
}
```

It can then be accessed by going:

```
const date:Confidence<Date> = new Date();
date.confidenceLevel = .9;
```

This does not seem to be possible (and I get the feeling it is anti-pattern), however I can do

```
export type Confidence<T> = T & {
   confidenceLevel:number
}
```

Which appears to accomplish what I want to do though I feel like I'm cheating doing this.

I recognize this "reverse extension" could be problematic if I overwrite a property of the generic type, but is that the only concern? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this, what is the best way to create a type that merely adds a property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a longstanding feature request, [microsoft/TypeScript#2225](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225), which asks for the ability to do `interface Foo<T> extends T {...}` the way you are asking for it.  It's not implemented yet (and might never be).  Right now you can only make an interface that `extends` an object type with *statically known keys*.  The unspecified generic type parameter `T` does not work because the compiler cannot predict what keys it will have.

You should rest assured that an [intersection](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) is a reasonable way of achieving this (with the caveat that you will not be warned if your added property conflicts with a property of `T`, as you noticed).  It is the [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225#issuecomment-137888000) solution in the aforementioned feature request.  Additionally, the [TypeScript library typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.2/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L286) for [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) use an intersection to represent the type of the result of adding properties to an existing object.  Therefore, with `Confidence<T>` defined like

```
type Confidence<T> = T & {
  confidenceLevel: number
}
```

you can easily write a function that produces one of these like this:

```
function makeConfidence<T>(x: T, confidenceLevel: number): Confidence<T> {
  return Object.assign(x, { confidenceLevel });
}
```

and use it:

```
const x = makeConfidence(new Date(), 0.9); // x is a Confidence<Date>;
console.log(x.getFullYear()); // 2020
console.log(x.confidenceLevel); 0.9
```

Looks good. Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsAmEEGMIB4AqAfFALxT5QBkUA3gFBRRaKobYQAyEAbhADYAuKAgCuAWwBGEAE50AvgzpIR2YCkRQxAQwDWEeMnSYcBQgAoAHkPwAaJiyPsuvQcPFTpASiEHWxvES0DFDSEMAi0ghQAPISAFYQWMAAdFoAzmkoAOYIlnY09oZsOM78UHKeANzydHTMCGnAUBakmrr6DsUQZggQAO5QACJawN2edgAMyQCcVVAA9PPNUChpUFqwnf64w6OE1fVpcHwQyXxwWZbJWWEAYiJ8fACaEFrSZp5zi1AATBN-dUQRxOZwuV3qficPH4cym0ygQA)

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check and the note about it being a requested feature! I think I am a little confused about interface vs type, but I think I'll save that for another day.

Comment: And if `T` is an optional type? like `type Confidence<T = never> = T & {...}`, this will return an undefined and not the rest `{...}`, any idea how to get around this?

Comment: 20 min later and found an solution, i will post it in case someone needs it

Answer (score 1):

Extending from the Accepted Answer by [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz):

If you want to make the generic type `T` optional, you can extend it from `Record<string, unknown>` and set the value to `Record<string, unknown>`.

```
type Confidence<
  T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
> = T & {
  confidenceLevel: number
};
```

And then you will be able to use it without any generic if needed:

```
interface Bar {
  barLevel: number
};

const foo: Confidence = { confidenceLevel: 100 };
const bar: Confidence<Bar> = { confidenceLevel: 100, barLevel: 2 };
```